# Entity Framework v4 POCO templates: repository returns object of incorrect type

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I've just implemented a repository based on EFv4 POCO entity templates.

When I do this

```
public Client Load(Guid firmId,
                   int prettyId)
{
    var client = (from c in _ctx.Clients where c.firm_id == firmId && c.PrettyId == prettyId select c).FirstOrDefault();
    return client;
}
```

the client returned is of type

```
{System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Client_8E92CA62619EB03F03DF1A1FC60C5B21F87ECC5D85B65759DB3A3949B8A606D3}
```

What is happening here? I thought I would get rid of any reference to types from System.Data.Entity namespace. The returned instance should be of type Client, which is a simple POCO class.

Comment: Apparently it has to do with a property ContextOptions.ProxyCreationEnabled and if we set it to false (default is true) it will not create proxy objects (those are the ones type DynamicProxies). But we also lose the ability of lazy loading. If someone has more insight on this topic, please do respond.

Comment: Also the ability of change tracking is supported by dynamic proxies.

Comment: **are you sure** you lose lazy loading when you disable proxy objects? I haven't heard of this issue before... (then again i disable lazy loading and eager load what i want)

Comment: Yes I've experienced it. The second I disabled ProxyCreationEnabled, referenced entities were missing from my objects. And that's also how I understand this article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456853.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can confirm that the solution is to set

```
context.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
```

which disables creation of dynamic proxy typed objects and leaves us with simple POCOs, which is what we were after with EF POCO templates in the first place.

But you lose lazy loading of navigation properties and change tracking on entities. For the first, you either have to use `context.LoadProperty()` or the `Include()` method on your ObjectQuery object. For the second, I do not know the solution yet (actually it doesn't really make sense to have change tracking on POCOs).

Also here is a similar question I would like to point out
[What are the downsides to turning off ProxyCreationEnabled for CTP5 of EF code first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4596371/what-are-the-downsides-to-turning-off-proxycreationenabled-for-ctp5-of-ef-code-fi)

Comment: There is "snapshot based" change tracking on POCOs without proxies, although it has some overhead and is slower than with proxies. Take a look at this article: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2009/06/10/poco-in-the-entity-framework-part-3-change-tracking-with-poco.aspx

Comment: Where can I see the proxy template?

Answer (score 0):

I agree that Mare's answer is correct. However, I would add a note of caution. 
If you run a query without this ProxyCreationEnabled setting set to true, then EF will return DynamicProxies. If you subsequently run a query with the setting set to false, then EF will return the cached DynamicProxies objects, regardless of the ProxyCreationEnabled setting.

Answer (score 0):

This can be configured globally for the EF context in the *Model.Context.tt file in  *Model.edmx under

```
if (!loader.IsLazyLoadingEnabled(container))
```

...

```
    this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
```

These will be added to the *Model.context.cs generated file, and will persist between updates from the Database.

I prefer this setting as I do not want a child object that matches the parent loaded from the database.

ALT: It can be configured for Json serizialization:
[JSON.NET Error Self referencing loop detected for type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7397207/json-net-error-self-referencing-loop-detected-for-type)