# Dumping Linq expression output to Console.

Tags: c#, linq

I have a linq expression which returns a list of objects. I want to dump that output to console in a pretty tabular format.

is there a way this can be achieved?

Comment: I've edited your question, see why:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I like to use [JSON.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/json) for serializing objects to string (in pretty tabular format). I also like to create extension method `Dump()` which outputs serialized object to console:

```
public static void Dump(this object value)
{
     Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value, Formatting.Indented));
}
```

Usage is simple:

```
items.Dump();
```

Comment: Thansk a lot Sergey. Can I use the same method with a datatable as well??

Comment: @gargmanoj yes, it will serialize DataTable also into array of objects like this `[ { "Column1": Value1, "Column2": Value2 }, { "Column1": Value3, "Column2": Value4 }]`

Comment: I am getting an exception "Self referencing loop detected for property 'Table' with type 'System.Data.DataTable'. Path 'Columns[0]'." when i use it with datatable.. using as dt.Dump<DataTable>();

Comment: @gargmanoj I think you need to add loops ignoring, like described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13510204/json-net-self-referencing-loop-detected