# Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException "Self referencing loop detected" in library code

Tags: json.net

I have self referencing data: each Item contains a list of Scrapbooks that it is a member of and each Scrapbook contains a list of Items it contains. Clearly that's circular, and so when a Scrapbook is serialised I get a Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException "Self referencing loop detected" error. We get around this on our Azure Mobile Services server by adding the line

```cs
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize;
```

in the `App_Start()` method of the `Global.asax.cs` file. But in the phone client I get the exception at this line of code:

```cs
await _ScrapbookTable.UpdateAsync(liveScrapbook);
```

where _ScrapbookTable is of type `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Services.MobileServices.IMobileServiceTable<Scrapbook>`.

[The documentation](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ReferenceLoopHandlingIgnore.htm) (and [other answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13549982/575530)) show how to fix this:

```cs
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(joe, Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings { ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore });
```

But this fix assumes that it is my code doing the serializing, rather than it being inside a call to an API function (in my case [`Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Services.MobileServices.IMobileServiceTable<Scrapbook>.UpdateAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj822306.aspx)).

Is there a way I could decorate the Item and Scrapbook classes with Json attributes (e.g. [`[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonObjectAttributeOptIn.htm)) to prevent the exception?

Comment: You might have a look at my answer on **[“Self Referencing Loop Detected” exception with JSON.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40472419/self-referencing-loop-detected-exception-with-json-net/51235783#51235783)** page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like all I need to do is add the [IsReference attribute](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/PreserveObjectReferences.htm) to my Item class:

```cs
[JsonObject(IsReference = true)]
public class Item
```

(as suggested as Fix 3 in [Boshoy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18223985/575530) to a similar question).