# JSON.Net Self referencing loop detected in API Controller

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, json.net

Environment:

- .net 4.6 1.0.0-rc1-update2
- Entity Framework core rc final.

My API controller is throwing this exception:

> An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Self referencing loop detected for property 'Site' with type 'Blog.Model.Site'. Path '[0].Menus[0]'.

How can I implement the fixes suggested here:
[JSON.Net Self referencing loop detected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13510204/json-net-self-referencing-loop-detected)

As far as I know, EF core does not implement lazy loading or proxy creation.

My controller simply returns the collection generated by this query:

```
public async Task<List<Site>> GetActiveSites()
{
    var query = db.Sites.Where(x => x.Active)
        .Include(x => x.Menus)
        .ThenInclude(m => m.MenuContentItems)
        .ThenInclude(x => x.ContentItem);

    return await query.ToListAsync();
}
```

Where:

- Site(1) -  Menu(*)
- Menu(1) - MenuontentItem(*)
- MenuContentItem(*) - ContentItem(1)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17313632/self-referencing-loop-detected-getting-back-data-from-webapi-to-the-browser See the answer provided by Stewart Hou.

Comment: did you find an actual solution for this?

Comment: @Drakoumel Yes, see link in comment above yours.

Comment: You might have a look at my answer on **[“Self Referencing Loop Detected” exception with JSON.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40472419/self-referencing-loop-detected-exception-with-json-net/51235783#51235783)** page.

Answer (score 0):

Create a view model without the bi-directional mapping that EF has. Populate that view model from your your ef query.