# Asp.Net Web API 2.0, Getting a complex object back from Get() action method

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-core-2.0

I have **two model classes** `ServiceProvider.cs & Club.cs` one service provider can have many clubs in it. However `ServiceProvider.cs` has a virtual collection of clubs in it. As shown below

```
public class ServiceProvider 
{
    public int ServiceProviderId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNo { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Club> Clubs { get; set; }
}
public class Club 
{
    public int ClubId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }

    public virtual ServiceProvider serviceProvider { get; set; }
    public int ServiceProviderId { get; set; }
}
```

I have **implemented a repository pattern** to query the MS Sql server, if i return my repository's `_serviceProvider` `GetAll()` method it works fine, and i get all the serviceprovider objects in `PostMan`.

```
public IEnumerable<ServiceProvider> Get()
    {
        return _serviceProvider.GetAll();
    }
```

But if i return the `GetAllWithClubs()` method of repository then i get run time exception here. **Problem is: I am unable to get all service providers along with their clubs collection.** However, i have already debugged my code before putting question here, I am getting all the service providers along with their clubs collection perfectly fine. I am sure data fetching from database is fine, problem coming in sending response back from Get() Action method.

```
public IEnumerable<ServiceProvider> Get()
    {
        return _serviceProvider.GetAllWithClubs();
    }
```

**Error i am getting in Postman is**
[image]
**output in visual studio is**
[image]

I have **tried searched solution** of `.toList()` in front of `GetAllWithClubs()` plus returning `ActionResult` which came with Asp.net core 2.1 (Not supported in my case 2.0). I believe this is not a duplicate question. 
Implementation of `GetAll()` and `GetAllWithClubs()` methods are below.

```
public IEnumerable<ServiceProvider> GetAllWithClubs()
    {
        return _context.ServiceProviders
            .Include(c => c.Clubs);
    }
```

In `Repository.cs`

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
    {
        return _context.Set<T>();
    }
```

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: @Stephen Muecke i have edited my question, kindly review now.

Comment: Your question still not state what the exception is

Comment: @StephenMuecke updated question with error

Comment: @ShahjahanKK "GetAllWithClubs() method of repository then i get run time exception here." which error return in you question you provide error of postman but what exactly error throw from your repository please mention that.

Comment: @LaljiDhameliya could you kindly check now, i have edited my question with vs error.

Comment: you need to start debugging your own code, put some breakpoints, see what data you get back when calling GetAll. Do you hit the endpoint at all? Do you get data back? There is a lot you can do on your end before throwing in the towel

Comment: @AndreiDragotoniu You Sir, i have already debugged my code before sending in here, I am getting all the service providers along with their clubs collection perfectly fine. i think data fetching from database is fine, problem coming in send response back from Get() Action method

Comment: when you say "I think data is fine" that doesn't mean you debugged anything.  You either know or you don't. which one is it?

Comment: 'Replace("i think", "I am sure");'

Comment: @ShahjahanKK might be Issue with "Self referencing loop detected" solution like either  you just change ConfigureServices method startup.cs for change AddJsonOptions in AddMvc() like services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options => options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore); or convert your object into json first then after return as json content.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13510204/json-net-self-referencing-loop-detected#45174502

Comment: @LaljiDhameliya yes, that's exactly what i have needed, It's working fine Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem** in above code: is **Json .net self referencing loop detection** and the **solution** is that, we have to **ignore loop references and not to serialize them** For doing this in Asp.net MVC 2.0 we have to put this code in `Startup.cs`.

```
services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(
                options => options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling =
                Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore);
```

Rebuild, problem solved.

Comment: A better option would be to create a viewmodel and populate it with the data you want and do not expose your domain model to the outside world.

Comment: in that case do we still be needing to ignore loop reference?

Comment: It depends on the shape of the data, but you could flatten the data or make the relationship one way which would remove the circular reference.