# How to use DevExtreme in partial view (ASP.NET MVC)?

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, devextreme

I try to use DevExtreme component in partial view.
But my partial view page shown when I click on the element.

And in the main page after the click I have error

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Self referencing loop detected for property 'ApplicationEntity' with type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.ApplicationEntity_50A6A66F1464C1DE4E8A736E85D88C5AF4F4249EAE26FB21C4F82592E001885D'. Path 'data[0].ApplicationEntity.ApplicationEntityHistories[0]'.
```

[browser console screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5csDF.png)

**Main page Code:**

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-7">
   <button id="btn">CLICK</button 

</div>
<div class="col-md-5" id="divPartialViewContainer">

</div>
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#btn").on("click", function () {
        var text = $(this).text().trim();
        if (text.length > 0) {
            console.log(text);
            $.ajax({
                url: '/RiskMap/RiskDetailsPartial/',
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: JSON.stringify({ 'param': text }),
                success: function (content) {
                    $('#divPartialViewContainer').html(content);
                },
                error: function (e)
                {
                    console.log(e);
                }
            });
        }
       });

     });
 </script>
```

**Controller Code**

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> RiskDetailsPartial(string param)
{          
  return PartialView("_RiskDetails", new List<Risk>());
}
```

**Partial View code:**

```
@model IEnumerable<Core.Models.Risk>
@using Core.Models
@using Core.ComplexTypes
@{
   ViewBag.Title = "Risks";
}

<h2>Risks</h2>

@(Html.DevExtreme().DataGrid<Risk>()
    .DataSource(Model)
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.AddFor(m => m.Id);
        columns.AddFor(m => m.Impact);
        columns.AddFor(m => m.Probability);

    })
  )
```

Comment: do you have Newtonsoft DDL in your project?

Comment: do you have Newtonsoft DDL in your project? Yes

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=JsonSerializationException%3A+Self+referencing+loop+detected&oq=JsonSerializationException%3A+Self+referencing+loop+detected&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58.176j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8 Are you using an entity framework class as your model, perhaps?

Comment: Yes, I add this **config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling
                    = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;**, in my WebApiConfig class, but it did not help

Comment: @SamatYeshernkulov if `ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore` doesn't help check other options suggested in my [answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49006427).

Answer (score 0):

The message is clear you just need to read it more thoroughly.

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Self referencing loop
>   detected for property 'ApplicationEntity' with type
>   'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.ApplicationEntity_50A6A66F1464C1DE4E8A736E85D88C5AF4F4249EAE26FB21C4F82592E001885D'.
>   Path 'data[0].ApplicationEntity.ApplicationEntityHistories[0]'.

Json serializer is attempting to serialize some kind of entity(lets call it **EntityA**) you passed to it, but the problem is that this entity contains another entity(lets call it **EntityB**) that contains the first entity(**EntityA**). This is going in circles!

This has also happened to me with my own ORM and I found out the problem is lazy loading. I solved it by adding an interface to each of my entities:

```
interface IJSonify
{
   object Json();
}
```

Here I simply return an anonymous object. Entity that implements this interface decides how it will represent itself as JSON object.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved it by declaring JsonConvert defaultSettings on webApplication init.

```
JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings
{
        Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented,
        ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
};
```

Apparently DevExtreme don't use standard ASP.NET MVC json serializer inside DataSourceLoader.Load(..) method, so if you set ASP.NET MVC json serializer ReferenceLoopHandling setting it is not enough.

Another solution is use [JsonIgnore] dataAnnotation above the property that generate the loop reference