# Swagger Response Formats sample exception

Tags: c#, api, swagger

I am getting this error message when I try to view my api in swagger help section. Is there something I need to add to stop this error?

```
Response Formats
application/json
Sample:
An exception has occurred while using the formatter 'JsonMediaTypeFormatter' to generate sample for media type 'application/json'. Exception message: Self referencing loop detected with type 'Model.Disease'. Path '[0].Types[0].List'.

text/json
Sample:
An exception has occurred while using the formatter 'JsonMediaTypeFormatter' to generate sample for media type 'text/json'. Exception message: Self referencing loop detected with type 'Disease'. Path '[0].Types[0].List'.

application/xml
Sample:
An exception has occurred while using the formatter 'XmlMediaTypeFormatter' to generate sample for media type 'application/xml'. Exception message: There was an error generating the XML document.

text/xml
Sample:
An exception has occurred while using the formatter 'XmlMediaTypeFormatter' to generate sample for media type 'text/xml'. Exception message: There was an error generating the XML document.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GuidelineDataLayer.Model.Disease is your own code? You have a circular reference in your object that's preventing the model from serializing. Go over your code again and make sure you don't have 2 classes pointing at each other.

Comment: Here's a pretty good post about resolving it, it looks like swagger has a built in "allow" method for this kinda thing.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17313632/self-referencing-loop-detected-getting-back-data-from-webapi-to-the-browser

Comment: Sorry after looking again it looks like that method is specific to newtonsoft

Comment: Yes I tried that and it worked text/json but not the xml