# How i can return JSON object in which relationship many-to-many (.net core)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I can't return a JSON object to my front-end. I use ASP.NET Core 2.0 WebApi

with _contex all good, and connect too.
I see data in debug, but I never found how I can return it.

```cs
            var user = _context.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Username == User.Identity.Name);

            var orders = _context.Orders
                .Where(o => o.UserId == user.Id)
                .Include(o => o.City)
                .Include(o => o.Products)
                    .ThenInclude(products => products.Product)
                .ToList();

            return new ObjectResult(new { orders = orders }) { StatusCode = 200 };
```

What I want to see on front-end:

```json
{"orders": [
         {
             "orderId": "1"
             "orderCode":"SAJVLUHC",
             "products" : [pr1...prn]
         },{
             "orderId": "2"
             "orderCode":"SAJVLUHC",
             "products" : [pr1...prn]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Self referencing loop detected - Getting back data from WebApi to the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17313632/self-referencing-loop-detected-getting-back-data-from-webapi-to-the-browser)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Order contains Product and Product contains orders, then json serialization might be failing with cyclic loop handling. You could try this in your configuration:

```
services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options =>
{
    options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
});
```