# EF Code First, Web API, Json serialization Many to Many

Tags: json, serialization, asp.net-web-api, many-to-many, entity-framework-5

Having som major problem with many to many relation.

```
public class Team
{
    public Team()
    {
        Users = new HashSet<User>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public User()
    {
        Teams = new HashSet<Team>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Cell { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Team> Teams { get; set; }
}
```

After Returning a newly added Team like this

```
var currentUser = _ctx.Users.Where(u => u.Username ==    HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name).SingleOrDefault();

        teamToAdd.Users.Add(currentUser);
        var teamAdded = _ctx.Teams.Add(teamToAdd);
        Save();

        return teamAdded;
```

I get the following error in the response inner exception:

```
"Self referencing loop detected with type 'MatchMaker.Data.Team'. Path 'Users[0].Teams'."
```

There is obviously a circular reference going on but i want a Team to be able to have many Users and a User to be able to have many Teams. Is there any way of getting past this withouth creating DTOs?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSON.NET Error Self referencing loop detected for type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7397207/json-net-error-self-referencing-loop-detected-for-type)

Comment: config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore; in the WebApiConfig.cs did the trick

Comment: Cool, glad to see that worked.

Comment: Is it possible not to load teams?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Entity framework self referencing loop detected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19467673/entity-framework-self-referencing-loop-detected)