# EF WebAPI Self Referencing Loop

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I am getting a self Referencing issue with EF and I'm trying to over come it but still allow the Service to be able to perform a GET passing in {[FromODataUri] int key} a key and return an IQuerable Obj to get the Expanded tables if necessary.   Below is a slimmed down version of the tables.  Any suggestions on how to handle the situation.

```
public class People
{
 public int PeopleId {get;set;}
 public string PeopleName {get;set;}

 public int? ProductId{get;set;}

 public virtual Product Product{get;set;}
}
```

The ProductId is a PK in Product but its not required. As per the convention it doesn't have to be Decorated with the PK DataAnnotation overide.

```
public class Product
{
   public Product()
   {
      PeopleCollection = HashSet<People>();
   }
   public int ProductId {get;set;}
   public string ProductName {get;set;}
   public virtual ICollection<People> Peoples{get;set;}
}
```

Comment: WebAPI is serializing your response, but Product references People, which references a product, which references people, which references product.  You may need to reconsider if having `Product` on your `People` class is necessary, or perhaps map your entities to a DTO which avoids this circular reference.

Comment: I should add, this is probably a symptom of having `lazy-loading` enabled, as the serializer is looking into the properties and then loading the entity.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19467673/entity-framework-self-referencing-loop-detected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out after some time.   The self referencing issue will come up if you are Inheriting from APIController but if you switch to inherit from ODataController everything works.

So

```
 public class MyController : ApiController
    {
     ..... Bunch of code here
    }
```

To

```
public class MyController : ODataController
    {
     ..... Bunch of code here
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case I recommend using DTO's or using anonymous objects, for example:

```
public IHttpActionResult Get() {
    var response = db.YourTable.Select(x=>new{
       x.PeopleId,
       x.PeopleName,
       x.ProductId,
       Product= new {
         x.ProductId,
         x.ProductName  
       }
    }).toList();
    return Ok(response);
}
```

Thats how I would do it with anonymous objects, If you want to use DTO's you just need to map them, hope this is what you are looking for.

For just a specific id:

```
public IHttpActionResult Get(int id) {
    var response = db.YourDb.Select(x=>new{
       x.PeopleId,
       x.PeopleName,
       x.ProductId,
       Product= new {
         x.ProductId,
         x.ProductName  
       }
    })Where(x=>x.PeopleId == id).toList();
    return Ok(response);
}
```

Note, this method is using query string parameters

Comment: Wouldn't this always return all the associated Tables?  for example if I flip this arround and I do a get on the product `code var rslt = db.Products.Select(x=> new { x.ProductId, x.ProductName, new List<People>(){ y = y.PeopleId, y.PeopleName, y.ProductId};code` would bring back all the Product and All the People in each call?

Comment: vs Using Odata Query where I could just make the GET to Product it would only return my Products and It wouldn't return any associated data Unless I added the ?$expand=People to my QueryString

Comment: @JoeRicklefs yes it will, if you want to search for an specific id add before .toList() this: Where(x=>x.PeopleId == key).toList(),

Comment: That would work except this service is queried through the URL  and I don't know what Fields/ or Conditions that will be sent over.  So the solution needs to be more flexible. If a user sends over just a Get to api/People  The services will only return the People information but if they send over Api/People?$expand=Product  the Result would include the people and the associated product.

Comment: @JoeRicklefs Oh I see, well a found a very good guide by microsoft: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/supporting-odata-query-options)

Comment: That doesn't help with the original issue.  I know how to query data using Odata, but EF is coming up with the Self Referenceing loops issue