# Entity framework self referencing loop detected in Unit of work pattern

Tags: c#, serialization, entity-framework-5, unit-of-work, self-reference

My current project following "Unit of Work" design pattern.I have two table like--

[image]

where MAINSCHMSTID is foreign key in detail table.when i am updating table.i am getting data before savechanges like this--

[image]

[image]

My Update Method Code:

```
    public void Update(TEntity entity)
    {
       db.Entry<TEntity>(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;                    
    }
```

notice that with MAINSCHMSTID 1 ,i am getting it's object(MAINTENANCESCHMASTER) also.In MAINTENANCESCHMASTER there is a MAINTENANCESCHDETAIL object and this self referencing loop is going on.Finally this does not save the data.It is giving a java script alert:
[image]

In Console --

[image]
I followed [Entity framework self referencing loop detected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19467673/entity-framework-self-referencing-loop-detected). But getting no result.Can anyone suggest what to do?

EDIT:

In AngularJs Controller my edit method --

```
function save() {

            scope.submitted = true;
            if (scope.maintenanceForm.$valid) {

                var result = null;
                var operation = null;
                if (scope.isEdit) {

                    operation = "edit";
                    scope.maintenance.MAINTENANCESCHDETAILS = scope.maintenance.maintenanceItemList;
                    result = maintenanceService.edit(scope.maintenance);
                }
                else {

                    operation = "save";
                    scope.maintenance.MAINTENANCESCHDETAILS = scope.maintenance.maintenanceItemList;
                    result = maintenanceService.save(scope.maintenance);
                }

                result.then(function (data) {

                    if (data == "") {

                        alert("Maintenance Schedule Item Already Exist");
                        initialize();
                    }
                    else {

                        alert("saved successfully");

                        if (!scope.isEdit) {
                            scope.maintenance.MAINSCHMSTID = data.ID;
                        }
                        convertSvc.updateCollection(scope.maintenanceViews, scope.maintenance, operation, "MAINSCHMSTID");
                        initialize();
                    }

                }, function (e) {
                    alert(e);
                });
            }
        }
```

error in console --
[image]

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type
>   'VMS.DATA.MAINTENANCESCHMASTER'.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: A circular
>   reference was detected while serializing an object of type
>   'VMS.DATA.MAINTENANCESCHMASTER'.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [InvalidOperationException: A circular reference was detected while
>   serializing an object of type 'VMS.DATA.MAINTENANCESCHMASTER'.]
>   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeValueInternal(Object
>   o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse,
>   SerializationFormat serializationFormat, MemberInfo currentMember)
>   +2533    System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeValue(Object
>   o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse,
>   SerializationFormat serializationFormat, MemberInfo currentMember)
>   +371    System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeCustomObject(Object
>   o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse,
>   SerializationFormat serializationFormat) +778
>   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeValueInternal(Object
>   o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse,
>   SerializationFormat serializationFormat, MemberInfo currentMember)
>   +2751    System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeValue(Object
>   o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse,
>   SerializationFormat serializationFormat, MemberInfo currentMember)
>   +371    System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeEnumerable(IEnumerable
>   enumerable, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse,
>   SerializationFormat serializationFormat) +186
>   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeValueInternal(Object
>   o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse,
>   SerializationFormat serializationFormat, MemberInfo currentMember)
>   +2699    System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeValue(Object
>   o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse,
>   SerializationFormat serializationFormat, MemberInfo currentMember)
>   +371    System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeCustomObject(Object
>   o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse,
>   SerializationFormat serializationFormat) +778
>   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeValueInternal(Object
>   o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse,
>   SerializationFormat serializationFormat, MemberInfo currentMember)
>   +2751    System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeValue(Object
>   o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse,
>   SerializationFormat serializationFormat, MemberInfo currentMember)
>   +371    System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Serialize(Object
>   obj, StringBuilder output, SerializationFormat serializationFormat)
>   +57    System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Serialize(Object
>   obj, SerializationFormat serializationFormat) +83
>   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Serialize(Object
>   obj) +44    System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext
>   context) +817
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +39
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1
>   filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext,
>   ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +116
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1
>   filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext,
>   ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +529
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +106
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c()
>   +321    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +185
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +42
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +133
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Object tag) +56
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +40
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +34
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +70
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +133
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Object tag) +56
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Object tag) +37
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +44
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, Controller controller) +39
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +62
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +133
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Object tag) +56
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Object tag) +37    System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +39
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +39
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +39
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +70
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +133
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Object tag) +56
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Object tag) +37
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   +40    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult
>   result) +38
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +9644037    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.6.1055.0

In Global.asax.cs--

```
protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);


            HttpConfiguration config = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;

            config.Formatters.JsonFormatter
                        .SerializerSettings
                        .ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore; 
        }
```

Comment: What do you **want** the code to do? What does it **actually** do? Does it throw any exceptions?

Comment: I want it will not show any error,will save the master and detail table.it does not throw any exception.Only showing a java script alert of error.

Comment: i edit my question.you can see the error.

Comment: I uploaded the code

Comment: @mjwills you can see the error now.

Comment: @mjwills edited

Comment: *I followed Entity framework self referencing loop detected. But getting no result.* What do you mean by "no result"?

Comment: Can you show us the code you added based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19467673/entity-framework-self-referencing-loop-detected ?

Comment: @GertArnold "no result" means--I got no solution.i applied code in Global.aspx and tried proxyenabled false in dbcontext.but still there is parent child loop.

Comment: @mjwills you can see the code now

Comment: You might have a look at my answer on **[“Self Referencing Loop Detected” exception with JSON.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40472419/self-referencing-loop-detected-exception-with-json-net/51235783#51235783)** page.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an error when trying to return a serialized version of the model back to the front end. You can get around it by setting the ReferenceLoopHandling property in your serializer:

```
var list = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model,
    Formatting.None,
    new JsonSerializerSettings() {
        ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
});

return Content(list, "application/json");
```