# Asp.Net Mvc Web Api Json Formatter issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, json.net, jsonserializer

First ı want to tell u my architecture.
My tale class for Tale table

```
public class Tale
{
    [ScaffoldColumnAttribute(false)]
    public int TaleId { get; set; }
    public string TaleName { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public string VoicePath { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Category> Category { get; set; }   
}
```

My category class for Category Table

```
public class Category
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Tale> Tales { get; set; }
}
```

Like that ı create my TalesCategory table

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Tale>()
           .HasMany<Category>(u => u.Category)
           .WithMany(r => r.Tales)
           .Map(c => c.ToTable("TalesCategory")
                       .MapLeftKey("TaleKey")
                       .MapRightKey("CategoryKey"));
```

And Its My TaleController:ApiController function

```
public IEnumerable<Tale> GetAllTales()
    {
        return TaleService.FindAllTale();
    }
```

My WebApiConfig

```
config.Formatters.Clear();
        config.Formatters.Add(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
```

if I write "/api/tales" ı want to list of my tale but ı take this error. I think I have to write JsonMediaFormatter and I try some code but ı didnt success. What can I do? I use .Net Framework 4.5.

```
{"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/json; charset=utf-8'.","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException","StackTrace":null,"InnerException":{"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Self referencing loop detected with type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Tale_B48C4EAA8B3983ECA938C57C1764611B3C06FAC3348891DAC636EBEBF05EA8E2'. Path '[0].Category[0].Tales'.","ExceptionType":"Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException","StackTrace":"   konum: Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.CheckForCircularReference(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonProperty property, JsonContract contract, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n   konum: Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeList(JsonWriter writer, IWrappedCollection values, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n   konum:
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSON.NET Error Self referencing loop detected for type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7397207/json-net-error-self-referencing-loop-detected-for-type)

Answer (score 0):

You need to break the circular reference that is being picked up because of the navigational property in your EF class.

Try

```
public IEnumerable<Tale> GetAllTales()
{
    return TaleService.FindAllTale().Select(x=> new Tale 
                    { 
                        TaleId = x.TaleId, 
                        TaleName = x.TaleName,
                        ... 
                     });
}
```

Comment: I got it but I want to see category id in this result. I edit my code with ur example {TaleId = x.TaleId, ... Category = x.Category} and ı take this error "An exception of type 'System.Data.EntityCommandExecutionException' occurred in System.Data.Entity.dll but was not handled in user code". I have some problem with ICollection<Category>. My brain a little confused because I use first time Code First...

Comment: use "Select" for category, too. Like this : `Category = x.Category.Select(y=> new Category { CategoryId = y.CategoryId, ... })`

Comment: Thanks for answer but now ı take convert type error. As I said Category is ICollection<> "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<MasalYuvasi.Entities.Category>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<MasalYuvasi.Entities.Category>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"

Comment: So sorry but now command execution exception :/ "An exception of type 'System.Data.EntityCommandExecutionException' occurred in System.Data.Entity.dll but was not handled in user code"

Comment: I cant still find any solution and I don't know why I take this error.