# Self referencing loop detected when serializing Data models in MVC5 / EF6

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, json.net

I am getting this error "Self referencing loop detected" while serializing using '**Json.NET**'

I have a Book model

```
public class Book
{
    public Book()
    {
        BookPersonMap = new List<BookPersonMap>();
    }

    public int BookId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<BookPersonMap> BookPersonMap { get; private set; }

    (And many other virtual Icollections)
}
```

And this is the BookPerson Mapping class:

```
public class BookPersonMap
{
    public int BookId { get; set; }

    public string PersonName { get; set; }

    public int PersonTypeId { get; set; }

    public virtual Book Book { get; set; } // Foreign keys

    public virtual PersonType PersonType { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to Serialize the Book object it throws:

`"Self referencing loop detected for property 'Book' with type  'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Book_57F0FA206568374DD5A4CFF53C3B41CFDDC52DBBBA18007A896 08A96E7A783F8'. Path 'BookPersonMap[0]'."`

I have tried the things suggested in some of the similar posts
Example:

1. **PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects** in Serializer settings returned a string with length 3 million!
2. **ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore** in Serializer settings : 
   `"An exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll but was not handled in user code"`
3. ^ Same luck with **"ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize"**
4. **MaxDepth = 1** : Infinite loop again.

Putting **[JsonIgnore]** on the virtual properties is working but it is a tedious task (because of numerous FK references) and not efficent, since if I miss one property and it will throw exception.

What is missing from above Json settings for them be not working?

Comment: Have you looked at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7397207/json-net-error-self-referencing-loop-detected-for-type)?

Comment: @Pheonixblade9 Yes. That is what I mentioned in the question. None of the JsonSerializerSettings mentioned [here on the msdn site](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Loop-Reference-handling-in-caaffaf7) except for [JsonIgnore] actually work.

Answer (score 1):

```
services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(opt => {
    opt.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
});
```

Comment: Use this in ConfigureServices fuction on Startup.cs file.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the best way to solve this type of error is to flatten your model using a view model.

Put a break point on your object before it is serialized and start drilling into the child properties. You will probably find that you can go on indefinitely.

This is what the serializer is choking on.

Comment: Yes. I ended up serializing `BookViewModel`. Still don't know why none of JsonSettings help in serializing this type of objects. I thought `MaxDepth = 1` would do the trick at least.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Constructor for your controller and put on it this line of code :
    db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
//db is the instance of the context.

Answer (score 0):

> For asp.net mvc 5 use this

Add the code below to your `Application_Start` method inside `globax.asax file` or `startup` file.

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {
       ..
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter
                    .SerializerSettings
                    .ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
}
```

Disable lazy loading and 
ensure your controller does not return

```
Json(..obj)
```

rather it should return

```
Ok(..obj)
```

Comment: I have mentioned this under *things that I have already tried* bullet points.

Comment: ensure your controller method is not returning Json(..obj) rather it should return Ok(..obj) and disable lazy loading