# Change JSON.NET Serialization Settings

Tags: c#, json.net, rabbitmq, easynetq

I am trying to send complex objects using EasyNetQ but I keep running into this exception because my object contains a list of child objects that reference back to the parent object:

```
Self referencing loop detected for property 'Parent' with type 'Domain.ParentItem'.
Path 'Entity.Children[0]'."}
```

I have tried changing the JSON.NET default settings like so, but it doesn't fix the issue:

```
JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    Formatting = Formatting.Indented,
    ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
};
```

How can I change the default settings of the Json serializer so I can get around this issue without having to create separate DTO objects?

Edit: I have tried the suggestions in the possible duplicate (as I put in my original post) and it did not solve the issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSON.NET Error Self referencing loop detected for type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7397207/json-net-error-self-referencing-loop-detected-for-type)

Comment: How are you serializing your objects?  Are you sure you are using the default settings?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to create a class that implements the [`ISerializer` interface](https://github.com/EasyNetQ/EasyNetQ/blob/master/Source/EasyNetQ/ISerializer.cs).

For example:

```
public class MyCustomSerializaer : ISerializer
{
    // Add appropriate implementation containing your custom 
    // serialization/deserialization logic here
}
```

Next, you need to create a method that will register an instance of this class with an instance of `IServiceRegister`:

```
public void RegisterServices(IServiceRegister serviceRegister)
{
   serviceRegister.Register(serviceProvider => new MyCustomSerializer());
}
```

Note: for clarity, I am writing `RegisterServices` as a separate method; however, you could use an `Action<IServiceRegister>` instead for brevity if you wish.

Finally, provide `RegisterServices` as an argument when you call `RabbitHutch.CreateBus`:

```
var bus = RabbitHutch.CreateBus(connectionString, RegisterServices);
```

This will ensure that `bus` will use your custom serialization class instead of EasyNetQ's default serializer. Be careful to ensure that your producers and consumers are using compatible serializer implementation; otherwise, your consumers will receive messages that they are unable to deserialize.

Note that EasyNetQ allows other components to be replaced as well. For more information, see [here](https://github.com/EasyNetQ/EasyNetQ/wiki/Replacing-EasyNetQ-Components).