# How to force a query to retrieve nested elements data?

Tags: c#, json, linq, serialization, linq-to-sql

I'm making a `JSON` from my Database made with `LINQ to SQL`. I've set up `Serialization Mode Unidirectional` (so I can serialize data), and once I query my Object (`User`) I convert it to `JSON`:

```
[WebMethod]
public User GetUserByID(int ID)
{
    User user = db.User.Where(p => p.ID == ID).FirstOrDefault();
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user, new IsoDateTimeConverter());
    return user;
}
```

The problem is that on the resulting `JSON`, the nested data/objects (i.e. the relationship I have for that Object to others Object/Tables) are `null`.

So, for example, if I have 3 Phone numbers (1-n relationship) for that user, instead of retrieve a `JSON` array with these (3) numbers, it puts:

```
"Phones": null,
```

how can I "force" the `User` to be queried with all data/relationship inside it?

And if I do this query (for example) before serialize:

```
var phones = m_oAlumno.Telefono.ToList();
```

it says "Self referencing loop detected for type 'User'."

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7397207/json-net-error-self-referencing-loop-detected-for-type

Comment: @Ric i think problem in first place is linq not loading nested entities!

Comment: That post had some answers regarding nested entities, thought it could be useful

Answer (score 0):

In LINQ to SQL you can load referenced entities using DataLoadOptions.

```
var loadOptions = new DataLoadOptions();
loadOptions.LoadWith<User>(u => u.PhoneNumber);
db.LoadOptions = loadOptions;
```

Where PhoneNumber is an entity that references User and assuming **db** is your linq data context.

Comment: Uhm, but how can I "automate" this process? If I add a new table in the future, I'd like to "not" load manually in the code the new table :O

Comment: And anyway, it says the same: `Self referencing loop detected for type 'User'.` I can use `PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects` but it adds futile fields :(