# How to serialize the Dictionary object in c#

Tags: c#

can i able to serialize the type 
       `new Dictionary <int, List<className>> ();`

I have tried with this
               `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(object);`

But it is showing the error "**self referencing loop detected for type**"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7397207/json-net-error-self-referencing-loop-detected-for-type Take a look here

Comment: Can you give us the className description?