# Entity Core query returns only one item when eagerly loading navigation property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

Working with Entity Core creating a simple restful Web API. The issue I'm having is that when querying with a simple `context.Users.ToListAsync()` I receive a list of all the users in the database, but, when loading a One to One relationship navigation property (`context.Users.Include(u => u.Status).ToListAsync()`), I ALWAYS receive only the first item in my database.

Here are my Code First models:

```
public class User
{        

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get { return LastName + ", " + FirstName; } }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Avatar { get; set; }
    public string GUID { get; set; }
    public string InternalId { get; set; }

    // Foreign keys and navigation properties
    public virtual UserStatus Status { get; set; }
}

public class UserStatus
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // Foreign keys and navigation properties
    public virtual List<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

Each user must have a user status. User status should be a table of possible status states. There will be many users with a single status type. Here are my fluent mappings:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        // Users
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasAlternateKey(p => p.GUID);

        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasAlternateKey(p => p.InternalId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasAlternateKey(p => p.Email);

        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .Property(p => p.FirstName)
            .HasMaxLength(40)
            .IsRequired();

        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .Property(p => p.LastName)
            .HasMaxLength(40)
            .IsRequired();

        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .Property(p => p.Email)
            .HasMaxLength(250)
            .IsRequired();

        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasOne(p => p.Status)
            .WithMany(s => s.Users)
            .HasForeignKey("StatusId")
            .OnDelete(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

        // User Status
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserStatus>()
            .Property(s => s.Name)
            .HasMaxLength(40)
            .IsRequired();

    }
```

And here is the simple data initialization I'm testing with:

```
        List<UserStatus> status = new List<UserStatus>();

        status.Add(new UserStatus { Name = "Invited" });
        status.Add(new UserStatus { Name = "Registered" });
        status.Add(new UserStatus { Name = "Verified" });
        status.Add(new UserStatus { Name = "Deactivated" });

        foreach (UserStatus s in status)
        {
            context.UserStatus.Add(s);
        }
        context.SaveChanges();

        List<User> users = new List<Users>();

        users.Add(new User {
            FirstName = "Jack",
            LastName = "Test",
            Email = "JackTest@aol.com",
            GUID = "TEST001",
            InternalId = "00001",
            Status = status[0]
        });
        users.Add(new User
        {
            FirstName = "Jane",
            LastName = "Tester",
            Email = "JaneTester@gmail.com",
            GUID = "TEST002",
            InternalId = "00002",
            Status = status[1]
        });

        foreach (User u in users)
        {
            context.Users.Add(u);
        }
        context.SaveChanges();
```

In my web API Control, purely for testing, I'm doing the following:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
    {
        var users = await context.Users
            .ToListAsync();
        return new OkObjectResult(users);
    }
```

This works fine. I get a list of my users. BUT if I do this:

```
       [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
        {
            var users = await context.Users
                .Include(u => u.Status)
                .ToListAsync();
            return new OkObjectResult(users);
        }
```

I ever only get the very first entry in my database. If I do this:

```
       [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
        {
            var users = await context.Users
                .Include(u => u.Status)
                .LastAsync();
            return new OkObjectResult(users);
        }
```

Instead of the first entry I get the last, which implies to me that the entire list IS being worked with, at least up until the ToListAsync call.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Is the One to One relationship setup incorrectly? My data initialization? I can't figure this one out.

Comment: Duplicate of [JSON.NET Error Self referencing loop detected for type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7397207/json-net-error-self-referencing-loop-detected-for-type) (see OP's self-answer below).

Answer (score 1):

Debugging helped me find the solution, who would have thought?

I was getting a Loop Reference handling error from the Json serializer. My models are, of course, using circular references for navigation properties. I solved the issue by ignoring these when serializing. Specifically using this solution on another question:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38382021/7087278

That solution describes the process for ASP.net Core, which is what I needed.