# Fiddler ReadResponse() failed: The server did not return a complete response for this request. Server returned X bytes

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, fiddler

I have one-one relationship between profile and user entities.

```
    internal async Task<Profile> GetProfileByEmail(string email)
    {
        var user = await dbContext.Users
            .Include(u => u.Profile)
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Email == email);

        return user.Profile;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> Email(string email)
    {
        Profile profile = await userService.GetProfileByEmail(email);

        var jsonOptions = new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented
        };
        return Json(profile, jsonOptions);
    }
```

When I call `Email action` **from the browser it works normally** (I got my expected Json response). However, when I have **Fiddler active** to capture the requests and responses, I get this error in the browser:

> [Fiddler] ReadResponse() failed: The server did not return a complete response for this request. Server returned 1.064 bytes.

Why is that happening, am I doing something wrong?

I have to point out that when I remove the `.Include(u => u.Profile)`, I got the expected response without any error (the response is null because the profile is not loaded).

Could someone explain that error for me and how can I solve it?

Comment: Include causes a self-referencing loop. Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7397207/json-net-error-self-referencing-loop-detected-for-type

Comment: @Smit, but why only in Fiddler? why not in returning `Json` type?

Comment: Ah, I missed that it worked in browser.