# Referencing an object inside another object causes JsonSerializationException

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, json.net

I am new to Unity/C# and having difficulty converting two objects into JSON.

The goal is to build a JSON object that looks as follows:

```
{
    "operation": "pin",
    "question": {
        "studentPin": "123456"
    }
}
```

In Java I would simply do the following:

```
Question question = new Question();
question.setStudentPin(pin);
ServerRequest request = new ServerRequest();
request.setOperation(Constants.PIN_OPERATION);
//set the values entered for the pin entered
request.setQuestion(question);

String json = gson.toJson(request);
```

However, when I do the following in C#

```
 //Creating a new Question object
 Question question = new Question();
 question.studentPin = pinNumber.text;
 ServerRequest request = new ServerRequest();
 request.operation = Constants.PIN_OPERATION;
 //set the values entered for the pin entered
 request.question = question;

 string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request);
```

I get the following error:

**JsonSerializationException: Self referencing loop detected for property 'question' with type 'Question'.Path**

I have googled this error and understand that this usually happens when in your model classes there is a reference back to a parent object and that parent object has a reference back to its child object, which causes a circular reference during serialization.

However, I am unsure how exactly I can go about resolving these issues.

My Question class is set-up as follows:

```
public class Question : MonoBehaviour {

    public string studentPin;

}
```

My ServerRequest class is set-up as follows:

```
public class ServerRequest : MonoBehaviour {

    public string operation;
    public Question question;


}
```

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you try:  var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request, Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
});

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSON.NET Error Self referencing loop detected for type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7397207/json-net-error-self-referencing-loop-detected-for-type)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Consider using `JsonUtility.ToJson()` instead.
2. If `Question` and `ServerRequest` are mainly used to store data only, consider not subclassing it from `MonoBehaviour`.

In all:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class Question {
    public string studentPin;
}

[System.Serializable]
public class ServerRequest {
    public string operation;
    public Question question;
}

//Do your instantiation, setups, etc as above.
string json = JsonUtility.ToJson(request);
```

Read more about Unity's serialization [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/JSONSerialization.html).

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `JsonSerializaerSettings` class and setup reference-based serialization:

```
 JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
 {
    PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.All,
    ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize
 };

 string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request, settings);
```