# .Net Core 2.0 returning BadRequestObjectResult causes Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Self referencing loop detected

Tags: .net-core, json.net, azure-web-app-service

I have a controller which in certains cases returns `BadRequest(exception)`.
When debugging locally, everything works as expected, and I am getting a 400 response, and the body contains a valid JSON of the exception.

However, when the server runs on azure (app service), when the `return BadRequest(exception)` is executed, I am getting an invalid JSON, and also an exception is being thrown on the server side:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Self referencing loop detected for property 'manifestModule' with type 'System.Reflection.RuntimeModule'. Path 'targetSite.module.assembly'.
```

In the stack trace I can clearly see that it comes from:

```
  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.JsonOutputFormatter.WriteObject(TextWriter writer, Object value)
  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.JsonOutputFormatter.<WriteResponseBodyAsync>d__9.MoveNext()
```

This is clearly related to the `BadRequestObjectResult`.

Can someone explain this issue please ?

Comment: Do your response object contains a property which is the response object itself?

Comment: as I have said, the response object inherits from Exception, and this type doesn't hold any reference - just a simple constructor which passes the string message to base

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JSON.NET Error Self referencing loop detected for type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7397207/json-net-error-self-referencing-loop-detected-for-type)

Answer (score 0):

It really depends what type of exception is being thrown originally (Not the serialization error), but I think the most likely scenario is that you have an Exception object that contains an "Inner Exception", and somewhere along that path it has a "Parent Exception" or similar that points it back to it's parent. Thus you end up in a serialization loop.

You really have two ways to solve the problem.

1. You don't serialize the Exception object itself, but instead a DTO of the exception. I think this is probably the best way to solve the problem. An Exception object has not been designed with JSON Serialization in mind.
2. Since you are using JSON.NET, it actually has a setting that will stop looping when it detects it's inside one. You configure it in your ConfigureServices method on Startup :

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(x => x.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore);
    }
```

This will also work but it's not a proper solution IMO as you still have a self reference loop, it's just that JSON.NET will cut off serialization for you.

More info : https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2020/03/15/fixing-json-self-referencing-loop-exceptions/