# Hangfire, EF dbContext and the JSON reference loop

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, hangfire, ef-core-3.1

I want to use Hangfire to run background tasks with database operations from my ASP.net Core API.

I installed the Hangfire nuget and set the SQL dbConnection in the `Startup.cs`:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseSqlServerStorage(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
```

When I now want to start a background job like:

```
var jobId = BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => RebuildVersionHistoryCacheAsync(statisticContext));
```

I get an error like:

```
JsonSerializationException: Self referencing loop detected for property 'Context'  ...
```

I tried both, set the global serializer settings to ignore loops and set the hangfire settings doing the same:

```
services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
    {
      options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
    });
```

...

```
services.AddHangfire((sp, config) =>
     {
       config.UseSerializerSettings(new JsonSerializerSettings() { ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore });
     });
```

With no effect.

Is there something I miss in the configuration of Hangfire?
Or is there a base problem with Hangfire in combination of EF Core Database Contexts in BackgroundJobs?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JSON.NET Error Self referencing loop detected for type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7397207/json-net-error-self-referencing-loop-detected-for-type)

Comment: or this https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2020/03/15/fixing-json-self-referencing-loop-exceptions/

Comment: Nothing of the mentioned hints worked - I rebuild it without Hangfire