# Something went wrong when convert front List object to Json using Newtonsoft.Json

Tags: c#, asp.net

i'm working on .net framework project. I got this weird result when i was trying to convert list object to json string, result was correct at first element
[image]

But move to second one, result was:
[image]

I just dont know where $ref: 24 came from. Here is the method that processing list -> json:
[image]

Pls show me how can i fix this? :((

Answer (score 1):

The `PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects` setting tells the serializer to serialize objects by reference rather than by value. If you want to see all properties listed for all objects, remove this from your serialization call:

```
public static string Convert(object data)
{
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
        data, 
        new JsonSerializerSettings { Formatting = Format.Indented });
}
```

Comment: Seems like this didn't work for me, I got 'Self reference loop detected...' when use this block of code :(

Comment: @HarryStormborn The easiest fix is setting the serializer to ignore reference loops, but it depends on your needs. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7397207/json-net-error-self-referencing-loop-detected-for-type