# Self Reference loop EntityFramework problem, another way to solve it?

Tags: reference, entity-framework-core, self

My project is Web Api Core 5.0 and i have got problems with self reference loop EntityFrameworkCore

In my last project i have used this:

```
  services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(options => 
                options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore);
```

but on my current version .Net core it's not working,
i found something like this:

```
    services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options =>
    {
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.Preserve;
    });
```

but I dont like it, it shows $Id and $value on response, which i dont want to see
Is there another way of the way get rid of that self reference loop?

I read before:
[JSON.NET Error Self referencing loop detected for type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7397207/json-net-error-self-referencing-loop-detected-for-type)

and these don't help me

Comment: Using what you used in your last project: If you're using swagger -- you might look at [this](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/blob/master/README.md#systemtextjson-stj-vs-newtonsoft)  The key is to add the `services.AddSwaggerGenNewtonsoftSupport();` line just after the `AddSwaggerGen` block.

Comment: https://www75.zippyshare.com/v/Op8kXqvB/file.html

Comment: Still I can't - there bellow is a screenshot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was only a suggestion ... because your questions is about EF -- but the contents seem to stem from NewtonSoft and possibly Swagger.  So I thought it might have more to do with Swagger for your reference loopoing issue.  In any case, I've found this solves that type of issue for me. (you would need Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Newtonsoft)

First add NewtonSoft options.

```
   services.AddControllers()
       .AddNewtonsoftJson(opts =>
       {
           //opts.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
           //opts.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.StringEnumConverter());
           opts.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
       });
```

Then add swaggergen... and then newtonsoft support.

```
    services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
    {
        ...
    });
    // NOW add 
    services.AddSwaggerGenNewtonsoftSupport();
```

Comment: My man! It works now, thank you a lot! :D