# Self Referencing loop detected for property 'manifestmodule' | While adding certificate to GET request

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi

I have below code for GET request -

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Method="GET";
request.Timeout=300000;

X509Certificate2 certificate= new X509Certificate2(path,password);
request.ClientCertificates.Add(certificate);
```

**While adding certificate I am getting Error -**

```
Self Referencing loop detected for property 'manifestmodule' with type 'System.Reflection.RuntimeModule' Path 'Exception.Targetsite.Module.Assembly'
```

I searched on internet with respect to this error , but its general occurance is while using / parsing json which I am nowhere doing in my code.

I am using `.NET core - 2.1.1`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JSON.NET Error Self referencing loop detected for type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7397207/json-net-error-self-referencing-loop-detected-for-type)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you already found out this is an error coming from the Newtonsoft JsonSerializer. I think what's happening is that inside your API an exception is occurring, which is then passed to Newtonsoft to serialize to JSON so it can be returned as a response. Your options are either to fix this exception or disable reference loop detection mechanism.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc()
        .AddJsonOptions(
            options => options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
        );
}
```