# How can i solve waiting for server response taking lot of time

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm using asp.net core : 2.1 version,

Lets say i'm calling an API and when i call it takes 17 or 18 seconds to hit the controller.So my question is this problem causing from server side or from my API. Ill share the image and my controller code. After it hit the controller the process goes fast there is no wastes of time in service. I'm new to asp.net core and i'm confused what is causing this issue. If there is any probable solution provide me.
[![Image][1]][1]

Comment: You should check what happened for the _patientAppointmentService's ExecuteFunctions method. Why it takes so long time . For exmaple, you could add timer inside this function to check which steps takes so long time.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably because of ExecuteFunctions method , but there is no info about that method.

If you use Deserializing or Serializing methods in it, I have encountered a problem like this. It was because of Deserializing the object which comes from my Database..

And this was my solution : [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7397207/json-net-error-self-referencing-loop-detected-for-type)

if you don't use Serializing or Deserializing methods, share more details...

Comment: i have shared my service code please check

Comment: First, at line 8 , "list" you get from GetAppointmentList must be checked, I see nothing about that. And then you get a response from "GetPatientAppointmentList" but it is used by ExecuteFunctions method and there is also no info about that. If you use MSSQL, I suggest you to follow logs from SQL Server Profiler (You can find it on Tools menu). If you don't, you should check step by step with breakpoints and find the exact problem and then ask the question again.

Comment: Ok ill check that but. My problem is that it takes time in hitting the controller after that the service executes fast. Ok ill find out further more and i'll leave a reply here

Comment: Ok, I thought it was because of your services... then check the project, if it is before hitting the controller, you can also check your Program.cs (or Startup.cs if it is before .NET6.0) pipeline. Good Luck :)