# The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly

Tags: c#, wcf, web-config, app-config

Problem:

The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly.
This happens on my WCF service that is hosted on the visual studio 2010 built in development server.

Information:

this does not happen all the time I believe it is a "big Data" issue, I have googled as hard as I can but non of the solutions I have implemented have fixed anything (and I have tried most of them out there) I most likely am just missing something stupid.

Question:

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Client app.Config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
            <section name="Program.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
              <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000"
                 maxBufferSize="20000000"
                 maxBufferPoolSize="20000000">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32"
                 maxArrayLength="200000000"
                 maxStringContentLength="200000000"/>
              </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:62753/Service1.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" contract="ProgramService.IService1"
                name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
        </client>
      <behaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
          <behavior name="EndpointBehavior">
            <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
          </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
      </behaviors>
    </system.serviceModel>
    <applicationSettings>
        <Program.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="Program_PROGRAM_Screen" serializeAs="String">
                <value>http://localhost/IntegrationTest/SOAP/PROGRAM.asmx</value>
            </setting>
        </Program.Properties.Settings>
    </applicationSettings>
</configuration>
```

Service web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="1200" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
  </system.webServer>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ProgramEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Program.csdl|res://*/Program.ssdl|res://*/Program.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=ACUMATICA1-HPI7;initial catalog=Program;persist security info=True;user id=sa;password=$0l0m0n;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

WCF Activity Log Erro Message:

> There was an error while trying to serialize parameter
>   http://tempuri.org/:ScenarioSummaryResult. The InnerException message
>   was 'Type
>   'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.ScenarioSummary_A170028D0330F7804BAB85D00BA1EB45FA1754C8A6F6E98C0F003F15078E23A9'
>   with data contract name
>   'ScenarioSummary_A170028D0330F7804BAB85D00BA1EB45FA1754C8A6F6E98C0F003F15078E23A9:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies'
>   is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver or add any
>   types not known statically to the list of known types - for example,
>   by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the
>   list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.'.  Please see
>   InnerException for more details.

Service Information:

I am trying to return a list of Entity Framework stuff

```
//IService1.cs
[OperationContract]
List<ProgramService.ScenarioSummary> ScenarioSummary(string Module);

//Service1.svc
public List<ProgramService.ScenarioSummary> ScenarioSummary(string module)
        {
            return (from p in Entity.ScenarioSummaries where p.ModuleId.Equals(Entity.Modules.FirstOrDefault(q => q.ModuleName.Equals(module)).Id) select p).ToList();
        }
```

additional Information:

Any help/explanation of my clear incompetence in this matter and how to correct it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to increase the timeouts in the binding conf? Like `<binding ... receiveTimeout="10:00:00" sendTimeout="10:00:00">...`. Just to make sure, that not such a timeout is the cause of the problem.

Comment: enable tracing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271517/how-to-turn-on-wcf-tracing and check out there.

Comment: "I have googled as hard as I can" -jvanh1- post:The underlying connection was closed
question line: 7

Comment: @jvanh1 - That wasn't the message I was talking about.  I was talking about the error message in the activity log: `There was an error while trying to serialize parameter http://tempuri.org/:ScenarioSummaryResult.`. Glad you found the issue though.

Comment: httpruntime maxRequestLength?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some one commented that my error looked alot like [What are the downsides to turning off ProxyCreationEnabled for CTP5 of EF code first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4596371/what-are-the-downsides-to-turning-off-proxycreationenabled-for-ctp5-of-ef-code-f)

and that actually turned out to be my solution. They have since deleted their posting. Thank you mysterious stranger with greater googling skills than I.