# Entity Framework modifying Context.cs file changes does not persist

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

```
 public MyEntities()
        : base("name=MyEntities")
    {
        /*
         * If DbContext.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled is set to false, 
         * DbContext will not load child objects for some parent object unless Include method is called on parent object.            
         * Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4596371/what-are-the-downsides-to-turning-off-proxycreationenabled-for-ctp5-of-ef-code-f
         */

        this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    }
```

I have modified the MyDataModel.Context.cs file. I referred to [this Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4596371/what-are-the-downsides-to-turning-off-proxycreationenabled-for-ctp5-of-ef-code-f).

Issue I am having is, every time I change the edmx file (delete a table or add a new table from the database), this file gets reconstructed. So this change I did gets lost.

How can I preserve this change? is there a config setting for this?

Answer (score 2):

You should not modify any of the generated files. Modify the T4-Template instead. In the Solution Explorer open the tree of your EDMX-Model, here you find a file named *.Context.tt, open it and modify the section where the ctor is created. In my case this is on line 60 of the Template.

After saving the tt-File, it normaly automatically runs and creates the code you want. These changes are restored every time you modify and save the EDMX-Model.

Btw: You may not override an existing ctor in a partial class. But in general, partial class files are also a good way to extend generated objects with further functionality.