# ProxyCreationEnabled and LazyLoadingEnabled

Tags: entity-framework

what is the relation between lazyloadingenabled and proxycreationenabled in context configuration

```
public CorrespondenceContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
        this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = true;
    }
```

what i noticed is when ProxyCreationEnabled=false lazyloading missed its function 
that meaning that when `this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true; this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;`

I have to use Include when using related objects

is ProxyCreationEnabled override LazyLoadingEnabled ??

Comment: You are right that LazyLoading does not work when `ProxyCreationEnabled == false`. This is because lazy loading works by adding additional code into your model classes to support lazy loading. This additional code is added by subclassing your model class, and the resulting subclass is called a proxy. By disabling the proxy creation, there is no hooks for EF to lazy load. In theory you could manually add them yourself and the two configs would be independent.

Comment: Quite a good answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4596371/what-are-the-downsides-to-turning-off-proxycreationenabled-for-ctp5-of-ef-code-f

Comment: @Aron. Your comment is the perfect answer. Why don't you rite it as answer instead of comment?

Comment: @Aron thank you for your answer, but if I make ProxyCreationEnabled=true and LazyLoadingEnable=false it runs as it=true and no need for include, what I understand that if ProxyCreationEnabled=true and lazyload =false so it is eagearload and I have to use include, please I need clarification