# EF 6.1 Difference between ProxyCreationEnabled and LazyLoadingEnabled

Tags: c#, entity-framework

In your DbContext you can configure the following two parameters:

```
context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = true;
context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
```

My understanding is that to enable lazy loading you have to be able to create proxies for the entities. In other words both parameters need to be set to true to enable lazy loading.

**1. Why do both parameters exist and why can you configure both parameters?**

**2. What would the effect of the following configurations be?**

```
// Can't create proxies but can lazy load
context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;

// Can create proxies but can't lazy load
context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = true;
context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```

Comment: is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4596371/what-are-the-downsides-to-turning-off-proxycreationenabled-for-ctp5-of-ef-code-f the answer ?

Answer (score 10):

AFAIK:

- proxy creation **true** and lazy loading **true** =>

  - change tracking
  - lazy loading
- proxy creation **true** and lazy loading **false** =>

  - change tracking
- proxy creation **false** and lazy loading **true** =>

  - ...

reference (among others): [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592886.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How do proxies change the way change tracking works?

Comment: with no proxy, no tracking. So `context.SaveChanges()` will never do anything.

Comment: I think change tracking has nothing to do with the proxy, basically as far as my understanding both of them are used together to enable lazy loading, enable proxy only has no benefit, unless you can give specific code sample that explain that, and I just tried disabled both, `Find(1)`, change the prop, then `SaveChanges`, do save the changes

Comment: I just found this article [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2009/06/10/poco-in-the-entity-framework-part-3-change-tracking-with-poco.aspx). It appears change tracking will still work it just works in a different way

Comment: you are right, `SaveChanges()` does the job, but the context has to evaluate the changes and can't give them to you before the save, neither after as the entity state stays unchanged.

Comment: Proxies are needed for tracking because they are meant to replace the real entity instance with a proxy that contains the entity and some extra properties that allow the tracking: mainly the `State` property, with values `Added`, `Unchanged`, etc. Without these properties EF is missing important information to figure out what to persist, so `SaveChanges` doesn't always work as expected (it is not that it doesn't work at all, new entities are still detected and saved, but other changes can be missed and not persisted).