# Passing a model with a foreign key relationship via Ajax/Json from controller to view

Tags: ajax, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, foreign-keys, repository-pattern

I recently made a change to my database - I added foreign key relationships to certain tables and in doing so certain AJAX/Json calls no longer seem to accept the data I am trying to send it.

I had a model called Cars (which I could call via Ajax):

```
public partial class Cars
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> WorkCenterId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string SerialNumber { get; set; }
}
```

which now has an additional element:

```
public partial class Cars
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> WorkCenterId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string SerialNumber { get; set; }

    public virtual WorkCenter WorkCenter { get; set; }
}
```

so the Ajax call is this:

```
function GetCars() {     
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            url: '@Url.Action("GetCarList", "Line")',
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (data) {
                alert('it worked!');
            }
        }); 
    }
```

I am also using unitofwork/repository pattern BTW and this is the controller (which used to work fine):

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetCarList()
{
    var carlist = unitOfWork.CarRepository.Get().ToList();
    return Json(carlist);
}
```

No matter what I do now, I cannot get the data returned to the Ajax call (the alert does not fire). If I replace the CarRepository with another model repository that does not have any foreign key relations it will work again.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you added the CarsId in the WorkCenter Entity?

Answer (score 0):

OK I figured it out, I cannot serialize carlist unless I convert it to a POCO.

instead of that I just followed the suggestions from this post:

[What are the downsides to turning off ProxyCreationEnabled for CTP5 of EF code first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4596371/what-are-the-downsides-to-turning-off-proxycreationenabled-for-ctp5-of-ef-code-f)

I turned ProxyCreationEnable to false.