# Best place to enable lazy loading in entity framework 6

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, dbcontext

What is the best place to keep lazyloading enable condition in my web application. Because when I am using database first approach of EF and when try to update the context then my all setting got wiped out. Below are my settings.

```
  public DBEntities(): base("name=DBEntities")
    {
        this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = true;
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
    }
```

What is the best way so that these setting should not vanish after edmx update. Is there any chance to keep in global.asax. If yes what are its downsides?.

Comment: `true` is the default, so you shouldn't need these explicit settings.

Comment: Are these both statement set to true by default?.

Comment: Yes.. see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4596371/what-are-the-downsides-to-turning-off-proxycreationenabled-for-ctp5-of-ef-code-f) for a related SO explanation

Comment: And "Lazy Loading Enabled" is a setting in the property grid of an EDMX.

Answer (score 0):

Your placement looks fine. Note, that as Gert Arnold has stated, that these are defaulted to `true`.

So,

```
 public DBEntities(): base("name=DBEntities")
    { }
```

Is all you need for the sake of brevity here, excluding explicitness.