# WCF Service not returning virtual property ServiceProvider

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, wcf

```
public class Account
{
    [DataMember]
    public int AccountId { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ServiceProvider")]
    [DataMember]
    public int ServiceProviderId { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public virtual ServiceProvider ServiceProvider { get; set; }
}
```

When tried with

```
this.context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
this.context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
```

it return `ServiceProvider` as `null`

Comment: It returns error when this.context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true; // this.context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = true;The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.

Comment: Post your `ServiceProvider` entity here too.

Comment: If you are exposing EntityFramework to WCF you should look in to using [WCF DataServices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd673932(v=vs.110).aspx), it is specifically built to handle issues like the one you ran in to.

Comment: [DataContract]
    public class ServiceProvider
    {
        [DataMember]
        [Key, Column("ServiceProviderId", Order = 0)]
        
        public int ServiceProviderId { get; set; }
         [DataMember]
        public int Id { get; set; }
         [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }
         [DataMember]
        public string ContactPersonName1 { get; set; }
         [DataMember]
        public string ContactPersonName2 { get; set; }
        
      
        
    }

Answer (score 1):

Use eager loading with Include method:

```
using System.Data.Entity;
//...
context.Accounts.Include(x => x.ServiceProvider).Where(...)
```

See this topic for clarification:
[What are the downsides to turning off ProxyCreationEnabled for CTP5 of EF code first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4596371/what-are-the-downsides-to-turning-off-proxycreationenabled-for-ctp5-of-ef-code-f)

Comment: My Data from db is coming successfully to service method but not able to send it to client

Comment: You can have serializations issues, misconficuration of client\server or client side model problems. Make sure [DataContract] is set everywhere. Check if Account without Provider work or not. Check client side model(Account has Provider member).

Comment: Yes its working fyn without provider and i know its a serialization issue but what issue :-) i have used DataContract and DataMember properly and when i use lazy loading =false, serviceprovider is null but it reaches client successfully

Comment: Ok, first you need ProxyCreationEnabled = false as proxies you get from context can't be serialized. Second, in case of ProxyCreationEnabled = false you need to load ServiceProvider with separate query or your initial query for accounts should contain a direct instruction to load ServiceProvider and this is done by Include method i wrote in the answer. You can start with selecting provider  with distinct query and assigning it to account to make sure that Account with not null Provider and ProxyCreationEnabled =false serialized succesfully.