# Does a LINQ query return all the records from database?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Would an Entity Framework LINQ-to-Entities query return all records (even 10 million rows) from a database, or would there be any limitation on retrieval record size?

Comment: limitation will be when you get to `OutOfMemoryException`. What is the case you are dealing with? What are you planning on doing with the data?

Comment: I personally never use LINQ2Entities for such a query, i rather write stored procedures and use Dapper to map them and return the data. but as if its possible? yes it is. it depends on the server and many other things.

Comment: When retrieving that many records you are really archiving the database.  So check if the database has any archiving tools.

Answer (score 1):

Entity Framework and LINQ don't have any limitations for how many rows they can fetch. A problem you might face is making your server out of memory, since you're trying to retrieve that amount of data at once.

You should consider using something like Dapper as Valkyriee mentioned in the comments, or at least disable `proxy` if you still want to use Entity Framework:

```
using(var db = new MyDbContext())
{
    db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    var data = db.Users.ToList(); // suppose you have 10 milion users
}
```

...just be aware of what [disabling proxy will cause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4596371/what-are-the-downsides-to-turning-off-proxycreationenabled-for-ctp5-of-ef-code-f).  I'd still recommend using Dapper for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Normally fetching 10 million records from database at one shot is not a good practice. You can use Entities recommended pagination functionalities.