# Turning off proxies results in no associations

Tags: c#, wcf, entity-framework

I am working on a project where we use WCF and Entity Framework.
Because WCF wouldn't work with dynamic proxies, taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3372895/datacontractserializer-error-using-entity-framework-4-0-with-wcf-4-0), I have put this line in the constructor of my context class:

```
public CarBatteryEntities() : base("name=CarBatteryEntities")
{
    base.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
}
```

WCF works, however my linq queries wouldn't return their associations.

This is my code:

```
List<Edge> edges = edgeRepository.GetBatteryCenterEdges("cityname").ToList();
foreach(var e in edges)
    Console.WriteLine(e);
```

Class `Edge` has 3 main variables - `BatteryStation`, `BatteryStation` and `distance`.
It is an auto-generated class from the ET, both `BatteryStation` are connections to the other table.

If I use `ProxyCreationEnabled` as `true` everything works as a charm.

If I use `ProxyCreationEnabled` as `false` only `distance` would be returned correctly and both objects (`BatteryStation` and `BatteryStation1`) will be `null`.

Any suggestions?

```
public IList<Edge> GetBatteryCenterEdges(string name)
{
   var query = context.Edge
                      .Where(edge => edge.BatteryStation.name.Equals(name) 
                                  || edge.BatteryStation1.name.Equals(name))
                      .AsEnumerable()
                      .SelectMany(edge => new[] { 
                          edge, 
                          new Edge() { 
                              BatteryStation = edge.BatteryStation1, 
                              BatteryStation1 = edge.BatteryStation, 
                              distance = edge.distance 
                          } 
                      });

   return query.ToList();
}
```

Comment: Can you list the source for `GetBatteryCenterEdges`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've turned off proxies, you probably need to load the associations with [Include()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738708%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Use `Include()` to perform eager loading:

```
using System.Data.Entity; // for Include extension method.

var results = ctx.Edges
    .Include(e => e.BatteryStation)
    .Include(e => e.BatteryStation1)
    .ToList();
```

Or perform explicit loading on each entity:

```
var results = ctx.Edges.ToList();

foreach(var e in results)
{
    ctx.Entry(e).Reference(x => x.BatteryStation).Load();
    ctx.Entry(e).Reference(x => x.BatteryStation1).Load();
}
```

Comment: On `Include(e => e.BatteryStation)` it returns an error which says "cannot convert lambda expression to type string

Comment: It's an extension method in System.Data.Entity. This version is preferred over the one which takes a string, as it enables refactoring and will result in a compile-time error if one of those properties is missing. Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as an extend method as follows .It is generic method to include any entities which is having relationship,and you can also do the same for any N number of includes by using an expression which returns the navigation properties to be with eager loaded.

```
public IQueryable<TEntity> GetAllIncluding(params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] includeProperties) 
{
   IQueryable<TEntity> queryable = GetAll();
   foreach (Expression<Func<TEntity, object>> includeProperty in includeProperties) 
   {
      queryable = queryable.Include<TEntity, object>(includeProperty);
   }

   return queryable;
}
```